# Capture dataChanged event on QTreeWidget only for actual item

Tags: c++, qt

I want to capture check/unchecked events on a `QTreeWidget`, but I want only events from the item that "triggered" the change. Example:

```
t/
  a
  b
```

If I check/uncheck `a` I want a single event for `a`, not the event for `t` or its parents, and if I check/uncheck `t`, I only want the event on `t`, not `t` and all its childs.

Is there any way to do that?

I've looked through Qt documentation and found no way of doing this using `dataChanged`, or `itemChanged`. I have looked at `itemClicked` but it fires for different event (just selecting the row), and not for keyboard events.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue, I found a solution, simple to implement, but kind of weird... The idea is to use custom `QTreeWidgetItem` and a custom event in `setData`. The issue is that `setData` is called recursively for the children and parents of the item, so I used a guard to avoid triggering the event:

```
class CustomTreeWidgetItem : public QTreeWidgetItem {
  static CustomTreeWidgetItem* emitter;
public:

  // Bring constructors:
  using QTreeWidgetItem::QTreeWidgetItem;

public:

  void setData(int column, int role, const QVariant& value) override {
    if (emitter == nullptr) {
      qDebug() << "Role changed: " << text(column) << (checkState(column) == Qt::Checked);
      emitter = this;
    }
    QTreeWidgetItem::setData(column, role, value);
    if (emitter == this) {
      emitter = nullptr;
    }
  }
};

CustomTreeWidgetItem* CustomTreeWidgetItem::emitter = nullptr;
```

One can emit a custom event instead of the `qDebug()` line above.

I am using a `static` in the code for the sake of simplicity but a better solution would be to use a custom `QTreeWidget` which stores the guard and retrieve using `treeModel()` in `setData`.